# CoreData retrieving values in 1 to many

Tags: ios, core-data

I've been struggling with this all day. I have a CD model that has an entity sales_rep which has a 1 to many relationship to another entity named customers.

I can retrieve and display the sales_rep data, stored here:

```
SALES_REP_DATA* thisSalesRepData
```

and I can get the count for the number of customers:

```
thisSalesRepData.hasCustomers.count
```

this returns the right number of records (in this case 37)

but I can't get the customers information. I didn't set the CD up so the entity is CUSTOMER but the class is CUSTOMER_DATA.

If I do this:

```
NSArray* arrCustomers = [thisSalesRepData.hasCustomers allObjects];

for(CUSTOMER_DATA* thisCustomer in arrCustomers) {
      DDLogVerbose(@"%@", thisCustomer.customer_name);      
}
```

I get NULL

If I log thisCustomer I get:

```
Thursday, 07 November 2013 | 15:14:37 | AppViewController | getClientList: | 312 | <CUSTOMER_DATA: 0x8c85260> (entity: CUSTOMER; id: 0x8c849a0 <x-coredata://AC4450A8-3D03-4E9A-8EFD-47055FA0683A/CUSTOMER/p173> ; data: <fault>)
```

How can I get the customer info?

Edit: Here's how I am setting the customer - I've validated dictThisCustomerRevised has values.:

```
//loop

//get the entity description for this class
                NSEntityDescription* customerEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CUSTOMER" inManagedObjectContext:_moc];

                //init class
                CUSTOMER_DATA* thisCustomer = [[CUSTOMER_DATA alloc]initWithEntity:customerEntityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:_moc];

                //populate it
                thisCustomer.cf1_level_1_cd = [dictThisCustomerRevised objectForKey:@"cf1_level_1_cd"];
                thisCustomer.customer_address = [dictThisCustomerRevised objectForKey:@"customer_address"];
                thisCustomer.customer_city = [dictThisCustomer objectForKey:@"customer_city"];
                thisCustomer.customer_zip_base = [dictThisCustomer objectForKey:@"customer_zip_base"];
                thisCustomer.customer_num = [dictThisCustomer objectForKey:@"customer_num"];
                thisCustomer.customer_name = [dictThisCustomer objectForKey:@"customer_name"];
                thisCustomer.customer_class_cd = [dictThisCustomer objectForKey:@"customer_class_cd"];
                thisCustomer.state_cd = [dictThisCustomer objectForKey:@"state_cd"];
                [arrSalesRepCustomers addObject:thisCustomer];

                NSSet* setSalesRepCustomers = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:arrSalesRepCustomers];

                [thisSalesRepData addHasCustomers:setSalesRepCustomers];

//save this
            NSError* error;
            [_moc save:&error];
```

Comment: Have you set the name for the customer? did you generate the `CUSTOMER_DATA` class manually or using interface builder? have you tempered with the default implementation of the `CUSTOMER_DATA` class?

Comment: Hi Dan, see the edits. I didn't use IB. Not that I know of though I don't think I understand the last question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `customer_name` is not set (since the log shows that you've got an actual customer instance).

Comment: Well, you can verify if `customer_name` is set by putting the following statement in the loop where you create entities: `NSLog(@"%@", thisCustomer.customer_name)`. If it isn't getting set, try `NSLogging` the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Your log statement of `thisCustomer` shows that it is retrieved correctly. Indeed, although you write "I get NULL" you actually get the customer data as expected.

Don't be confused by the word `fault` in your log statement. It just means that there are more details to be retrieved behind the scenes if they are needed. Nothing to worry about for you.

One thing that might help you, is to sanitise your entity names. Your code will become much more readable this way:

- Follow the Objective C convention to use Capitalized (not ALL_CAPS) class names.
- Use concrete English nouns, such as "SalesRep", "Customer".
- Use these also for relationship names, so "customers" instead of "hasCustomers" (which might be a suitable getter for a boolean attribute, but which is clearly out of place here).
- Avoid redundancy. A "city" attribute of a for a Customer entity does not have to be "customer_city". A simple "city" is enough.

Like this your code should become much more comprehensible and less error prone.

In order to get at your customer info, just log things like `thisCustomer.city` and you will see that it will be retrieved without problems.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. I wasn't referring to the value of  DDLogVerbose(@"%@", thisCustomer.customer_name); returning as null when it should have a value. Not the logging of thisCustomer - I understand (to a degree) about faults...but now I've got worse problems - my NSManagedObjectModel suddenly is not listing any entities...arghhh